# PHP web page - Preview CSV upload before inserting into database

Tags: php, html, csv, upload

I have a current web page using file upload with HTMl and PHP to read the CSV and insert into the database. This all works fine but I'm trying to find a fairly quick and painless way of showing the data to the user before submitting and inserting to the database. Right now my submit button posts to the PHP and immediately does a VAR dump and inserts to the DB. I'm hoping there's a fairly streamlined way to show it on the page as soon as the file is added to the upload box.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");

while(!feof($handle)){
$filesop = print_r(fgetcsv($handle, 0, ","));
}


$coldata = array();

$coldata[ "orderNumber" ] = $filesop[0];
$coldata[ "place" ] = $filesop[1];
$coldata[ "workOrderNum" ] = $filesop[2];
$coldata["lowSideMIUNum"] = $filesop[3];
//rest of array elements and insert statement
```

Comment: *"of showing the data to the user **before** submitting and inserting to the database"* - **and** - *"to show it on the page **as soon as** the file is added to the upload box"* - seem to contradict each other.

Comment: Sorry, this is a good point. The latter would be nice, but mainly I just need it to be shown before insertion to the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output it as an html table

```
$maxPreviewRows = PHP_INT_MAX; // this will be ~2 billion on 32-bit system, or ~9 quintillion on 64-bit system
$hasHeaderRow = true;

echo '<table>';

if ($hasHeaderRow) {
    $headerRow = fgetcsv($handle);
    echo '<thead><tr>';
    foreach($headerRow as $value) {
        echo "<th>$value</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr></thead>';
}

echo '<tbody>';

$rowCount = 0;
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    if (++$rowCount > $maxPreviewRows) {
        break;
    }
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: So would I run this and add a submit button to this page that runs insertion?

Comment: You'll need to either store the uploaded file somewhere so you can access it again, or include the source of that file as a hidden field on this page. The former is better since if the CSV file is large it might not even work and it could take a while to post it again.

Comment: As well you may want to limit the number of rows you process from the csv if you're dealing with large ones to act more of a preview rather than the entire thing.

Comment: I've tried that code with no luck, it's just running into errors so I'm trying it as it's own file. I would like to use this to only display the table on submit, then the confirmation page can have another submit button that runs my current insert code

Comment: If you post all your code I can see if I can point out why you're getting errors. Also post the errors you're getting.

Comment: Hey sorry, I meant to edit this. I got it working perfectly, thank you! I just attached a confirmation PHP to the submit button and added a new button on that page to submit the confirmed info which grabs my upload.php. Much appreciated!